# Positioning alternating un-nested DIVs relative to each other

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have 8 DIVs that alternate with respect to the content they hold.

```
DIV 1 - Category
DIV 2 - Sub-Category
DIV 3 - Category
DIV 4 - Sub-Category
etc.
```

The end goal, if possible, is to have the Category DIVs floating horizontally beside each other and the Sub-Category DIVs positioned below their corresponding Category DIV.

DIV 1            DIV 3            DIV 5             DIV 7

DIV 2            DIV 4            DIV 6             DIV 8

I am not allowed to change the current structure, such as nest DIV2 within DIV1.

I also want to keep away from absolutely positioning the Sub-Category DIVs due to the dynamic way the DIVs are created, which could result in changing widths, etc.

In essence, I want to be able to position a DIV relative to the DIV before it.

Comment: Why do you tag jQuery in this question? This is better done with just CSS

Comment: `div:nth-child(even)` and `div:nth-child(odd)`?

Comment: If you're going to down vote, please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: Your question is fairly clear, but please post some actual HTML. It makes experimentation easier for us.

Comment: that is fairly easy to do

    div { width:50%; float:left; height:200px; }

now they sit next to eachother side by side

Comment: @Sergio I tagged jQuery in case a CSS-only option wasn't available. More logic is available via jQuery.

Comment: Fiddle fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KhqyW/2

Comment: Can you add attributes to the divs?

Comment: @isherwood No, the DIVs are created dynamically on the back-end; I can't give each any specific attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -4em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ke22R/

Just play with the margins to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close. If it's important that your groups be oriented vertically instead, you may have to look into using multi-column lists. If the divs vary in height you'll need to add an additional wrap to create rows containing the desired number of groups.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KhqyW/7

```
div.group {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

var myDivs = $('div');

for (var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i += 2) {
    myDivs.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
}
```